# Can't parse simple json with python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I have a very simple json I can't parse with simplejson module.
Reproduction:

```
import simplejson as json
json.loads(r'{"translatedatt1":"Vari\351es"}')
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/simplejson/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/simplejson/decoder.py", line 335, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/simplejson/decoder.py", line 351, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 23 (char 23)
```

Anyone has an idea what's wrong and how to parse the json above correctly?

The string that is encoded there is: **Variées**

P.S. I use python 2.5

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be quite correct; `Vari\351es` contains an invalid escape, the JSON standard does not allow for a `\` followed by just numbers.

Whatever produced that code should be fixed. If that is impossible, you'll need to use a regular expression to either remove those escapes, or replace them with valid escapes.

If we interpret the `351` number as an octal number, that would point to the unicode code point U+00E9, the `é` character (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE). You can 'repair' your JSON input with:

```
import re

invalid_escape = re.compile(r'\\[0-7]{1,6}')  # up to 6 digits for codepoints up to FFFF

def replace_with_codepoint(match):
    return unichr(int(match.group(0)[1:], 8))


def repair(brokenjson):
    return invalid_escape.sub(replace_with_codepoint, brokenjson)
```

Using `repair()` your example can be loaded:

```
>>> json.loads(repair(r'{"translatedatt1":"Vari\351es"}'))
{u'translatedatt1': u'Vari\xe9es'}
```

You may need to adjust the interpretation of the codepoints; I choose octal (because `Variées` is an actual word), but you need to test this more with other codepoints.

Comment: This code was produced for/by Venda platform. Unfortunately, I can't change this behavior.
BTW - what would be a valid escaper?

Comment: Thanks, but the result is not what's supposed to be:
after rapair function we get "Varişes", while it should have been "Variées"

Comment: @diemacht: Updated already :-) Since you didn't specify what you expected, I had to guess, then updated my guess.

Answer (score 4):

You probably did not intend to use a raw string, but a unicode string?

```
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> json.loads(u'{"translatedatt1":"Vari\351es"}')
{u'translatedatt1': u'Vari\xe9es'}
```

If you want to quote the data inside the JSON string you need to use `\uNNNN`:

```
>>> json.loads(r'{"translatedatt1":"Vari\u351es"}')
{'translatedatt1': u'Vari\u351es'}
```

Please note that the resulting dict is slightly different in this case. When parsing a unicode string simplejson uses `unicode strings` for the keys. Otherwise it uses `byte string` keys.

If your JSON data does in fact use `\351e` than it is simply broken and no valid JSON.

Comment: Can I do it if the string is in some variable, for example:
s=r'{"translatedatt1":"Vari\351es"}' ? Thanks!!!

Comment: Just don't create the string that way. Get rid of the `r` prefix and use `u` instead if you want to create a string containing unicode data. If you really want to use quoting inside the JSON data you need to use `\u351e`.

Comment: @bikeshedder: I think the OP means that the *server* sent that data. The `r''` makes it easier to show us the raw data sent. Yes, that's broken JSON data...

Comment: U+351E is CJK Ideograph Extension A.. not certain that that is the correct interpretation either. I think you were closer with octal..