# Parsing JSON using Pandas - issue with additional \ escape characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm downloading files from S3 that contains JSON (like) data which I intend to parse into a Pandas dataframe using `pd.read_json`.

My problem is that the files dumped into the S3 bucket use an 'octal escape' formatting for non english characters but Python/Pandas objects to the fact that an escape for the `\` character is also included.

An example would be the string: `"destination":"Provence-Alpes-C\\303\\264te d\'Azur"`

Which prints as:

[image]

If I manually remove one of the `\` characters then Python happily interprets the string and it prints as:

[image]

There is some good stuff in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186839/python-replace-with) and although `.decode('string_escape')` works well on an individual snippet, when its part of the much longer string comprising thousands of records then it doesn't work.

I believe that I need a clever way to replace the `\\` with `\` but for well documented reasons, `.replace('\\', '\')` doesn't work.

In order to get the files to work at all I used a regex to remove all `\` followed by a number: `re.sub(r'\\(?=[0-9])', '', g)` - I'm thinking that an adaptation of this might be the way forward but the number needs to be dynamic as I don't know what it will be (i.e. using `\3` and `\2` for the example above isn't going to work')

Help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this works well. Very rarely I'm getting an error - chr() arg not in range(256). I've tried to pinpoint exactly where this is falling over although its tough as these files are massive!!

Comment: See the gist I linked in my second comment.

Comment: I've been thinking of re-opening actually, because you have octal escapes for UTF-8 bytes, not for Unicode codepoints. Related, not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have Python interpret `\ooo` octal escapes, repair the JSON with a regular expression, then parse it as JSON. I did so before in [similar circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674057/cant-parse-simple-json-with-python)

Your data has UTF-8 bytes escaped to octal `\ooo` sequences, so you are looking for a more limited range of values here:

```
import re

invalid_escape = re.compile(r'\\([1-3][0-7]{2}|[1-7][0-7]?)')  # octal digits from 1 up to FF
def replace_with_codepoint(match):
    return chr(int(match.group(0)[1:], 8))

def repair(brokenjson):
    return invalid_escape.sub(replace_with_codepoint, brokenjson)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> sample = '{"destination":"Provence-Alpes-C\\303\\264te d\'Azur"}'
>>> repair(sample)
'{"destination":"Provence-Alpes-C\xc3\xb4te d\'Azur"}'
>>> json.loads(repair(sample))
{u'destination': u"Provence-Alpes-C\xf4te d'Azur"}
>>> print json.loads(repair(sample))['destination']
Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur
```